# SSRS Show Toolbar on drill down sub report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have a dashboard SSRS report in embedded in another web app.
In this report there are drill down reports(too many).

By default I set rc:stylesheet=hideToolbar for this main report. So the toolbar is hidden.
Now we want to show the Toolbar on specific drill down reports(not all of them).

Is there a way to do this?

I have tried to create a new stylesheet but as I'm not able to change rc:stylesheet parameter when I'm calling the drilldown report it doesn't work.

Comment: from my understanding this is not possible. Once you have hidden toolbar. Maybe someone with more understanding could add helpful comments

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are trying to do and know that this is achievable through custom stylesheets as well alternatively via a custom SSRS Toolbar UI (via old 2005/2010 mgmt and Execution SOAP SSRS APIs*).

But that may be way overkill for your situation.

My best suggestion with the current out-of-box behavior of SSRS as of MSSQL 2019 (applies to 2016 as well) would be to create a custom link or imageLink inside those subreports that you want to have an SSRS Toolbar for which then either pops up a small new browser window above the main report (or on a new tab) with the subreport- and per default SSRS behavior the toolbar will be there, or, if you want to be explicit you can add the SSRS qs param "&rc:Toolbar=true" to that link.

I have actually used both approaches on projects. It really depends on the requirements, priority and time ya know?

Let me know if I can try to further help in any way if anything I shared was useful.

*here is a similar solution to your kind of problem (the SSRS REST API v1 and v2 can do many things but not as much as the old SOAP APIs could): [How to export SSRS 2017 report using REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47779772/how-to-export-ssrs-2017-report-using-rest-api)